# No upvoting on comments on elections page

Tags: support, comments, election, moderator-elections

I noticed that there is no upvoting in the comments on the moderator elections page. Is this something that was left out on purpose, or just something that is not implemented.

Comment: It's by design. See [Cannot upvote comments under an election nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245030/cannot-upvote-comments-under-an-election-nomination)

Comment: @DavidPostill, great! I guess posts from meta-se should pop up when I'm trying to write a new question on meta-su... I can't even mark the question as a duplicate :P

Comment: @DavidPostill post that as an answer ;p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### I noticed there is no upvoting in the comments on the moderator elections page

This is [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245030/cannot-upvote-comments-under-an-election-nomination):

> This was taken out a while back [along with
>   flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/221045/155160).
>
> Nobody seems to recall exactly what went bust there once flagging was
>   taken out, but for  the moment this is by design.

Source [Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245030/cannot-upvote-comments-under-an-election-nomination) by [Adam Lear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/155160/adam-lear)